# JSON to DataTable

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to serialize JSON text to DataTable, as in the following.

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(jsonText);
DataTable dTable;
dTable = (from p in list select p).CopyToDataTable();
```

I get the following error. How do I fix it?

**ERROR :**

```
Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
[System.String,System.String]]'.
```

Comment: It seems fairly obvious to me that this has nothing to do with DataTables, as the exception is being thrown in the first line. That's what you should be concentrating on.

Comment: Kindly check the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35546685/5292650
Its the most easiest one

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = "[{"clientID":"1788","projectID":"19"},{"clientID":"1789","projectID":"24"},{"clientID":"1790","projectID":"24"},{"clientID":"1790","projectID":"23"},{"clientID":"1790","projectID":"21"}]";

DataTable tester = (DataTable) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public object Deserialize(string jsonText, Type valueType)
{
    try
    {
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer json = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();

        json.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        json.ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
        json.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
        json.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonText);

        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
        object result = json.Deserialize(reader, valueType);
        reader.Close();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try This*

```html
public static DataTable JsonToDataTable(string Json)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, (typeof(DataTable)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string chk = ex.Message;
                dt = new DataTable();
            }
            return dt;
        }
```